# how to change accept and cancel buttons text for the MobileDatePicker component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The MobileDatePicker in the @mui/x-date-pickers pacakge contains accept/change buttons with default text OK/CANCEL.

In v4 the DatePicker component had a acceptLabel/cancelLabel prop to change the text of the buttons, but i find anything like that for the v5 component.

How can i change the text of the buttons in v5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to this this by writing a custom ActionBar component

```
const MyActionBar = ({
  onAccept,
  onCancel,
  onClear,
  onSetToday,
}: PickersActionBarProps) => {

  return (
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={onClear}> customCleanText </Button>
      <Button onClick={onCancel}> customCancelText </Button>
      <Button onClick={onAccept}> customAcceptText </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  );
};
```

And overriding the bar component in my MobileDatePicker component

```
<MobileDatePicker
  //...
  components: {{
    ActionBar: MyActionBar
  }}
  />
```

Comment: how to make onAccept only being called when user clicks over the "OK" button and not outside the modal?

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; I created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-rain-7ddsz5?file=/src/index.tsx) of how to achieve this with the either the Theme or LocalizationProvider.

Details

If you want to do this without a custom component you can pass translations VIA the Theme or `LocalizationProvider` component. The [documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/#translation-keys) isn't all that clear but if you reference the source for [PickersLocaleText](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/HEAD/packages/x-date-pickers/src/locales/utils/pickersLocaleTextApi.ts) you'll see labels you want. For the enUS example you can import the [enUS locale](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/33ffb894eb8a87121cbeb47eda621285c1152420/packages/x-date-pickers/src/locales/enUS.ts) and then provide your own strings.

From the bottom of the docs

`To create your own translation or to customize the English text, copy this file to your project, make any changes needed and import the locale from there.`

Answer (score 3):

I have made this i18n by creating a customPtBRLocaleText. Take a look:

```
const customPtBRLocaleText: Partial<PickersLocaleText<any>> = {
  okButtonLabel: "Ok",
  cancelButtonLabel: "Cancelar"
};


export default function ResponsiveDateTimePickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(
    dayjs("2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
  );

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
      adapterLocale={ptBR}
      localeText={customPtBRLocaleText}
    >
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <MobileDateTimePicker
          label="For mobile"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the real answer!